# using nltk to create logical sentences from a given list of words

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of words stored in a list on Python. I am trying to create logical sentences using these words and NLTK. How would I go about using NLTK to pick words from my list and form logical sentences?

Comment: That is a rather complex task, one that likely doesn't have any gold-standard solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435930/making-a-meaningful-sentence-from-a-given-set-of-words